# MYSQL: where column IN(Any_value)

Tags: php, mysql, where-in

I am trying to make a dynamic where clause. I am getting some array of check boxes in `PHP` as following code

```
$brand = array();
if(isset($_GET['brand']) && !empty($_GET['brand']))
    $brand=$_GET['brand'];  
    $brand_str = implode("' , '",$brand);  
}
```

MY SQL Query is

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products WHERE brand IN('$brand_str')";
```

if brand is not defined it gives error or no row is fetched but its a simple problem can be solved using following approach.

**MY approach:**

I use a variable like 'flag_for_filter_brand' inside if statement that is if flag_for_filter_brand=1 the QUERY is

```
$brand = array();
$flag_for_filter_brand=false;
if(isset($_GET['brand']) && !empty($_GET['brand']))
    $brand=$_GET['brand'];  
    $brand_str = implode("' , '",$brand);  
    $flag_for_filter_brand=true;
}


if(flag_for_filter_brand);
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products WHERE brand IN('$brand_str')";
else
     $sql="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products;
```

**MY PROBLEM:** 
But this is also a big problem because my code become so large because there are two three where clauses as below

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products WHERE brand IN('$brand_str') and Quantity IN ($var2) and type IN($var3)";
```

how to solve this in a optimal way?

Any suggestion or help is appreciated

Comment: A `WHERE` clause with multiple conditions isn't necessarily a bad thing.  What makes you think that it is?  Is it because it's running slower?  Is it because you think it looks ugly?

Comment: What do you mean by "my code become so large"?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @GigaWatt large code means i need to set and check lots of flag and also need to check pair of flags but i think i got a simplest ans from "barmer"

Comment: @MarcB its just a sample code in my actual for i used `mysqli_real_escape_string`. is the any other vulnerability is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each of your `WHERE` conditions in an array. Then test whether the array contains anything.

```
$wheres = array();

if(isset($_GET['brand']) && !empty($_GET['brand']))
    $brand=$_GET['brand'];  
    $brand_str = implode("' , '",$brand);  
    $wheres[] = "brand IN ('$brand_str')";
}
if(isset($_GET['quantity']) && !empty($_GET['quantity']))
    $quant=$_GET['quantity'];  
    $quant_str = implode("' , '",$quant);  
    $wheres[] = "Quantity IN ('$quant_str')";
}
// Repeat this for other conditions

if (!empty($wheres)) {
    $where_str = "WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $wheres);
} else {
    $where_str = "";
}
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Products $where_str";
```

If you have lots of conditions, you can put the names of the fields in an array, and then make the first part of this answer into a loop:

```
$fields = array('brand', 'quantity', 'type', ...);
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (!empty($_GET[$field])) {
        $field_str = implode("' , '", $_GET[$field]);
        $wheres[] = "$field IN ('$field_str')";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all parts of your `WHERE` condition in an array.

```
$where = array();

if(isset($_GET['brand']) && !empty($_GET['brand']))
    $brand_str = implode("' , '", $_GET['brand']);

    $where[] = "brand IN('$brand_str')";
}

...
```

then test if array is not empty

```
if (!empty($where)) {
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $where);
} else {
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `1` as `WHERE` value:

```
$brandArray = $_GET['brand']; // with empty(), isset(), and other validation...
$quantityArray = $_GET['quantity']; // with empty(), isset(), and other validation...
$typeArray = $_GET['type']; // with empty(), isset(), and other validation...

$whereArray = array();
$whereArray['brand'] = !empty($brandArray) ? 'brand IN (' . implode(',', $brandArray) . ')' : 1;
$whereArray['quantity'] = !empty($quantityArray) ? 'quantity IN (' . implode(',', $quantityArray) . ')' : 1;
$whereArray['type'] = !empty($typeArray) ? 'type IN (' . implode(',', $typeArray) . ')' : 1;

$where = implode(' AND ', $whereArray);

if(flag_for_filter_brand);
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products WHERE brand IN('$brand_str')";
else
     $sql="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products;

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT
        DISTINCT *
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        $where
;
SQL>>>;
```

That's just one possibility to handle this. Actually this code should be separated infor classes and methods or at least to some functions.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put the queries in a function and call that function inside your `if`

```
if(isset($_GET['brand']) && !empty($_GET['brand'])) {
   $brand=$_GET['brand'];  
   $brand_str = implode("' , '",$brand); 
   if !empty($brand_str) 
      myQueries( $brand_str );
 }

 function myQueries( $brand_str ) {
    // execute your queries
 }
```

Another option is if your script is doing only that to `exit` if your string is empty.

```
if(isset($_GET['brand']) && !empty($_GET['brand'])) {
   $brand=$_GET['brand'];  
   $brand_str = implode("' , '",$brand); 
   if empty( $brand_str )
     exit;
 }

 myQueries( $brand_str );
```

Comment: How does this answer show how to deal with all the combinations of different conditions?